# Jackson: can not get String value from JsonNode

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a root-JsonNode

```
JsonNode payloadNode;
```

with the following textValue  (log.warn("PAYLOAD_NODE" + payloadNode.textValue());):

```
 {"id":0,"uid":""}
```

But when I,m trying to get String-value from this node:

```
 JsonNode idNode = payloadNode.get("id");
```

I receive null

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#textValue()).

> Method to use for accessing String values. Does NOT do any conversions for non-String value nodes; for non-String values (ones for which isTextual() returns false) null will be returned. For String values, null is never returned (but empty Strings may be)

As it is a text value it is just a string that has no field "id".

So if you have something like this:

```
String s = "{\"id\":0,\"uid\":\"\"}";
payloadNode = om.valueToTree(s);
```

you would get such a log output if your JsonNode was just a string as in my example. You need to read your possible string as a json tree so like:

```
payloadNode = om.readTree(s);
```

Doing this will give you "0" for id and `null` for `textValue()`.